# Windows Media player new version looks like old

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-media-player

I have Windows 10 (I've upgraded it from Windows 7). My Media player,suddenly, has started looking weirdly. It looks like Media player of old version and the enhancement in the "view" menu doesn't work. I tried to update it, but it  writes that I have already the newest version. What could it be? This how my "Media player" looks:

[image: How Media player looks like]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you changed the visual settings of your media player

In order to change it back, click `View > Skin chooser` and choose what skins you like more.

Or if you want it to just view your library, click `View > Library`

[image]

Let me know if that helps!